# If cell is numeric only move to opposite cell

Tags: excel, vba

I found a code which does exactly what I need but I'm unable to make it loop through sheet2 and sheet3?

Does anyone have a suggestion?

```
 Sub MoveMyNumbers()

    MoveNumbers "sheet1", "b"
    MoveNumbers "sheet2", "b"
End Sub



Function MoveNumbers(ShtName As String, ColLetter As String)
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim ColNumber As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim i As Long

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
    lRow = ws.Range(ColLetter & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'Get Column Number from column letter
    ColNumber = ws.Range(ColLetter & "1").Column

    For i = 1 To lRow
        If IsNumeric(Cells(i, ColNumber).Value) Then
           Cells(i, (ColNumber + 1)).Value = Cells(i, ColNumber).Value
           Cells(i, ColNumber).Value = " "
           
        End If
    Next i
   End Function
```

Comment: The For loop is referencing  unqualified `Cells(...)` and are therefore referencing the ActiveSheet.  Prefix them with `ws.`

Answer (score 1):

### Move Values to Adjacent Cell

- It isn't working because you haven't qualified `Cells` in the `For Next` loop. Replace every occurrence of `Cells` in the `For Next` loop with `ws.Cells` or use the `With` statement:

**A Rewrite**

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveMyNumbers()
    MoveNumbers "Sheet1", "B"
    MoveNumbers "Sheet2", "B"
    MoveNumbers "Sheet3", "B"
End Sub

Sub MoveNumbers(ByVal ShtName As String, ByVal ColLetter As String, _
    Optional ByVal ColOffset As Long = 1)
     
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ShtName)
    lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColLetter).End(xlUp).Row
    
    For i = 1 To lRow
        With ws.Cells(i, ColLetter)
            If IsNumeric(.Value) Then
                .Offset(, ColOffset).Value = .Value
                .Value = " " ' don't you rather want blank ""?
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    
End Sub
```

- Each line in these line pairs does the same:

  ```
  lRow = ws.Range(ColLetter & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  lRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, ColLetter).End(xlUp).Row

  ColNumber = ws.Range(ColLetter & "1").Column
  ColNumber = ws.Columns(ColLetter).Column

  Cells(i, (ColNumber + 1)).Value = Cells(i, ColNumber).Value
  Cells(i, ColLetter).Offset(, 1).Value = Cells(i, ColNumber).Value
  ```

Comment: Perfect! thank you so much